# I need to count the number of times an element occurs and of the count is greater than 3, create a new xml document using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

For instance

```
<SCHOOL>
    <STUDENT NAME="BOB">
        <GRADE SCORE="50"/>
        <GRADE SCORE="10"/>
        <GRADE SCORE="20"/>
        <GRADE SCORE="40"/>
        <GRADE SCORE="90"/>
        <GRADE SCORE="30"/>
    </STUDENT>
</SCHOOL>
```

Transformed to

```
<SCHOOL>
    <STUDENT NAME="BOB">
        <GRADE SCORE="50"/>
        <GRADE SCORE="10"/>
        <GRADE SCORE="20"/>
    </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT NAME="BOB">
        <GRADE SCORE="40"/>
        <GRADE SCORE="90"/>
        <GRADE SCORE="30"/>
    </STUDENT>
</SCHOOL>
```

I have only just started working with xslt and have no idea how to accomplish this!

Comment: Ha! No, it is not homework, this example seems simple because I kept the example simple. It is simply part of a much bigger piece that got dumped on me at work and since this is not my area of expertise and I do not have time or resources to do a lot of research into XSLT, I thought I would seek help elsewhere. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does my answer suit you?

Answer (score 1):

This transform will do what you ask. I trust you have a good reason for asking other than being too lazy to do your own homework?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/SCHOOL">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="STUDENT"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="STUDENT">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="GRADE[position() mod 3 = 1]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="GRADE">
    <STUDENT>
      <xsl:copy-of select="parent::STUDENT/@*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select=".|following-sibling::*[position() &lt; 3]"/>
    </STUDENT>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<SCHOOL>
   <STUDENT NAME="BOB">
      <GRADE SCORE="50"/>
      <GRADE SCORE="10"/>
      <GRADE SCORE="20"/>
   </STUDENT>
   <STUDENT NAME="BOB">
      <GRADE SCORE="40"/>
      <GRADE SCORE="90"/>
      <GRADE SCORE="30"/>
   </STUDENT>
</SCHOOL>
```

Comment: I believe it might, I will let you know the outcome.  Thank you very much

Comment: Actually this did exactly what I needed it too, Thanks again Borodin!